# What level are the gyms?

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-fifth-generation

What level are the Pokemon in each Black and White gym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Striaton City

Cilan/Chili/Cress

- Level 12 Lilipup
- Level 14 Elemental Monkey

#### Nacrene City

Lenora

- Level 18 Herdier
- Level 20 Watchog

#### Catelia City

Burgh

- Level 21 Whirlipede
- Level 21 Dwebble
- Level 23 Leavanny

#### Nimbasa City

Elesa

- Level 25 Emolga
- Level 25 Emolga
- Level 27 Zebstrika

#### Driftveil City

Clay

- Level 29 Krokorok
- Level 29 Palpitoad
- Level 31 Excadrill

#### Mistralton City

Skyla

- Level 33 Swoobat
- Level 33 Unfezant
- Level 35 Swanna

#### Icirrus City

Brycen

- Level 37 Vanillish
- Level 37 Cryogonal
- Level 39 Beartic

#### Opelucid City

Drayden / Iris

- Level 41 Fraxure
- Level 41 Druddigon
- Level 43 Haxorus

Comment: I'm assuming the other trainer in the gyms are of lower levels?

Comment: That is a safe and reasonable assumption.